# Selenium's IE driver doesn't load page?

Tags: java, selenium, internet-explorer

I try to load webpage and extract some docs, but after typing in code and pressing "search" button, nothing shows up. When i do it on my regular website, it works fine. Should I somehow set my WebDriver differently?

I tried with simple firefox driver but it also failed.

```
    WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();


    driver.get("https://ekrs.ms.gov.pl/rdf/pd/");

    WebElement krsinput = driver.findElement(By.name("unloggedForm:krs2"));
    krsinput.sendKeys(String.valueOf(myNumber);

    WebElement szukajbutton = driver.findElement(By.name("unloggedForm:submit"));
    szukajbutton.click();
```

I typed in "331515" in the inputbox (there's only one) and after pressing "szukaj", there should be table showing below button.

Comment: What is your _Manual Step_ which you are trying to _Automate_? Where are you stuck exactly?

Comment: Searching company by it's number then downloading proper document (and name it but it's secondary goal)

Comment: _IE_ and _Firefox_ failed ... how about _Chrome_?

Comment: I cant make chrome work at all :/

Comment: Can u try this in debug mode by keeping a debug point at:
 szukajbutton.click(); Check whether the correct string is inputting in the text box. Also, try clicking the button on this screen to check if the issue is with the driver window.

Answer (score 0):

First, there is a tip on input field: *Pole KRS jest dziesięcioznakowe.*
So, your code should look like

```
String strMyNumber = "0000331515";

WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
driver.get("https://ekrs.ms.gov.pl/rdf/pd/");

WebElement krsinput = driver.findElement(By.name("unloggedForm:krs2"));
krsinput.sendKeys(strMyNumber);

WebElement szukajbutton = driver.findElement(By.name("unloggedForm:submit"));
szukajbutton.click();
```

And your code is fully workable.
By my opinion, it's a website's issue. I have tried few correct format case numbers that I've found on some Polish websites, all of them gave no result to me.